# How to access window object from component in spec file angular 7

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

```js
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  gettableaudata(){
    this.windowTableau.api= window;
    this.windowTab = this.windowTableau.api.tableau;  
    return  this.windowTab ;
  }

}
```

I have been trying to access window object of my component in my spec file , but the property( window.tableau) I am interested in is coming out to be undefined

I tried storing the window.tableau in a local variable or a method inside a component and tried accessing in the spec file but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't use the global scope. Also, please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] of your issue (or at least some code)

Comment: Please add the code which does not work or provide a minimal [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can(or even, should) use a custom Provider for window and mock it:

In your TestBed:

```
const windowMock: Window = { 
    tableau: () => {doSomething()}
};


TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ...
      { provide: 'Window', useValue: windowMock }
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Hi Eliran thanks for the rply! When i tried this the window object doesnt have the tabelau property on it it say its undefined

Comment: The tableau property on window object is only accessible when I run my local copy on the server and do console.log( window.tableau) , but when I run my karma tests its undefined

Comment: That's the reason you creating a mock window object who has this tableu prop on it...

Comment: So basically One can  not access the window tableau property in the spec file from the component